# Using Google Play Services as an Android Service to get location anytime from any activity

Tags: java, android, android-service

I am trying to create a Service in my application which will provide location to the activities (of the same app, not others) that need it. I would prefer to use `Google Play Services`

rather than `LocationManager`.

Could you give me an example of such a Service?
Also, how do I start it and how do I get the location from an activity?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a singleton to achieve it. I am on the move so could not suggest code. Create an application singleton and use it to create a singleton class where you receive the location. Fetch location from this file.